# Flyway Doesn't throw Exception

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, flyway

I'm currently adding flyway to a legacy system.

```
<bean id="flywayConfig" class="org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="routingDataSource"/>
    <property name="shouldCreateSchemas" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultSchema" value="myschema" />
    <property name="schemas" value="myschema" />
    <property name="validateOnMigrate" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <constructor-arg ref="flywayConfig"/>
</bean>
```

Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The configuration works well for success, but when flyway must throw a exception the follow message is displayed:

```
18:19:08,166 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.DatabaseType] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5454/mydatabase (PostgreSQL 11.5)
18:19:08,575 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Flyway Community Edition 7.0.4 by Redgate
```

Debbugging Flyway class from flyway-core version 7.3.0, the follow code block is found:

```
 public MigrateResult migrate() throws FlywayException {
        return (MigrateResult)this.execute(new Flyway.Command<MigrateResult>() {
            public MigrateResult execute(MigrationResolver migrationResolver, SchemaHistory schemaHistory, Database database, Schema[] schemas, CallbackExecutor callbackExecutor, StatementInterceptor statementInterceptor) {
                if (Flyway.this.configuration.isValidateOnMigrate()) {
                    ValidateResult validateResult = Flyway.this.doValidate(database, migrationResolver, schemaHistory, schemas, callbackExecutor, true);
                    if (!validateResult.validationSuccessful && !Flyway.this.configuration.isCleanOnValidationError()) {
                        throw new FlywayException("Validate failed: " + validateResult.validationError);
                    }
                }
... hide
}
```

The line `throw new FlywayException("Validate failed: " + validateResult.validationError);` is reached.

And the content of `validateResult.validationError` is :

```
Migration checksum mismatch for migration version 1.2
-> Applied to database : -1296604646
-> Resolved locally    : 2016009096. Either revert the changes to the migration, or run repair to update the schema history.
```

The message above is never displayed, but the follow message is displayed instead:

```
18:19:08,166 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.DatabaseType] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5454/mydatabase (PostgreSQL 11.5)
18:19:08,575 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Flyway Community Edition 7.0.4 by Redgate
```

I found [this](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/718) issue closed on github, but the problem stil persists.

Flyway is running on startup.

I'm tried the version 7.0.x and 7.3.0.

**Some extra information**

Wildfly 17

Java 8

The Caller of migrate() in Flywa.class method is

```
<T> T execute(Flyway.Command<T> command, boolean scannerRequired) {...}
```

With this block of code:

```
 Object result;
    try {
        database = databaseType.createDatabase(this.configuration, !this.dbConnectionInfoPrinted, jdbcConnectionFactory, (StatementInterceptor)statementInterceptor);
        this.dbConnectionInfoPrinted = true;
        LOG.debug("DDL Transactions Supported: " + database.supportsDdlTransactions());
        Pair<Schema, List<Schema>> schemas = this.prepareSchemas(database);
        Schema defaultSchema = (Schema)schemas.getLeft();
        parsingContext.populate(database, this.configuration);
        database.ensureSupported();
        DefaultCallbackExecutor callbackExecutor = new DefaultCallbackExecutor(this.configuration, database, defaultSchema, this.prepareCallbacks(database, resourceProvider, jdbcConnectionFactory, sqlScriptFactory, (StatementInterceptor)statementInterceptor, defaultSchema, parsingContext));
        SqlScriptExecutorFactory sqlScriptExecutorFactory = databaseType.createSqlScriptExecutorFactory(jdbcConnectionFactory, callbackExecutor, (StatementInterceptor)statementInterceptor);
         result = command.execute(this.createMigrationResolver(resourceProvider, classProvider, sqlScriptExecutorFactory, sqlScriptFactory, parsingContext), SchemaHistoryFactory.getSchemaHistory(this.configuration, noCallbackSqlScriptExecutorFactory, sqlScriptFactory, database, defaultSchema, (StatementInterceptor)statementInterceptor), database, (Schema[])((List)schemas.getRight()).toArray(new Schema[0]), callbackExecutor, (StatementInterceptor)statementInterceptor);  line
    } finally {
        IOUtils.close(database);
        this.showMemoryUsage();
    }
```

I forgot to say that the follow message is printed recursively, when there is some exception happens on background.

```
18:19:08,166 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.DatabaseType] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5454/mydatabase (PostgreSQL 11.5)
18:19:08,575 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) Flyway Community Edition 7.0.4 by Redgate
```

Execution Stack(retrieved from Intellij)

```
execute:172, Flyway$1 (org.flywaydb.core)
execute:164, Flyway$1 (org.flywaydb.core)
execute:538, Flyway (org.flywaydb.core)
migrate:164, Flyway (org.flywaydb.core)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:62, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:498, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invokeCustomInitMethod:1903, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
invokeInitMethods:1846, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
initializeBean:1774, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:593, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:515, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:320, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, 881394068 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$755)
getSingleton:222, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:318, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:199, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:307, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:199, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveReference:367, BeanDefinitionValueResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveValueIfNecessary:110, BeanDefinitionValueResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
applyPropertyValues:1681, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
populateBean:1433, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:592, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:515, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:320, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, 881394068 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$755)
getSingleton:222, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:318, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:199, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveReference:367, BeanDefinitionValueResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveValueIfNecessary:110, BeanDefinitionValueResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
applyPropertyValues:1681, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
populateBean:1433, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:592, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:515, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:320, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, 881394068 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$755)
getSingleton:222, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:318, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getTypeForFactoryBean:1543, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getTypeForFactoryBean:877, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
isTypeMatch:574, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBeanNamesForType:514, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBeanNamesForType:485, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors:227, BeanFactoryUtils (org.springframework.beans.factory)
findAutowireCandidates:1411, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doResolveDependency:1210, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveDependency:1167, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
inject:593, AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation)
inject:90, InjectionMetadata (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation)
postProcessProperties:374, AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation)
populateBean:1411, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:592, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:515, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:320, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, 881394068 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$755)
getSingleton:222, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:318, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:199, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
preInstantiateSingletons:849, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
finishBeanFactoryInitialization:877, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:549, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext:400, ContextLoader (org.springframework.web.context)
initWebApplicationContext:291, ContextLoader (org.springframework.web.context)
contextInitialized:103, ContextLoaderListener (org.springframework.web.context)
contextInitialized:187, ApplicationListeners (io.undertow.servlet.core)
call:216, DeploymentManagerImpl$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
call:185, DeploymentManagerImpl$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
call:42, ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
call:43, ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
lambda$create$0:105, SecurityContextThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security)
call:-1, 457618636 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$735)
lambda$create$0:1502, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1981354820 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$736)
lambda$create$0:1502, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1981354820 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$736)
lambda$create$0:1502, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1981354820 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$736)
lambda$create$0:1502, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1981354820 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$736)
deploy:250, DeploymentManagerImpl (io.undertow.servlet.core)
startContext:96, UndertowDeploymentService (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
run:78, UndertowDeploymentService$1 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:511, Executors$RunnableAdapter (java.util.concurrent)
run$$$capture:266, FutureTask (java.util.concurrent)
run:-1, FutureTask (java.util.concurrent)
 - Async stack trace
<init>:151, FutureTask (java.util.concurrent)
newTaskFor:87, AbstractExecutorService (java.util.concurrent)
submit:111, AbstractExecutorService (java.util.concurrent)
start:74, UndertowDeploymentService (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
startService:1737, ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask (org.jboss.msc.service)
execute:1699, ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask (org.jboss.msc.service)
run:1557, ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask (org.jboss.msc.service)
run:35, ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable (org.jboss.threads)
safeRun:1982, EnhancedQueueExecutor (org.jboss.threads)
doRunTask:1486, EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody (org.jboss.threads)
run:1377, EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody (org.jboss.threads)
run:748, Thread (java.lang)
```

Comment: So you see Flyway actually throwing the exception in your debugger? Are you able to continue the debug to the point where that exception is caught? Is it possible that it's being swallowed by the code that's invoking Flyway?

Comment: Yes I'm can see the exception being throwed, but only in in "Evaluation Expression...".

Apparently, the exception is never caught unless I haven't detected where.

Probably yes, but where? I updated my quest and past the execution stack. There is no extra configuration and the flyway_schema_history table is filled in correctly when all scripts are correct, but when there is an error, the table is not filled in informing which script is incorrect.